# Import bookmarked section from Word to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, import, ms-word

Hi I am trying toimport a bookmarked section (Bookmark at the beginning named "Start" and bookmark at the end named "End") form a word document to an Excel worksheet using VBA (in Excel).

I Tried the following code but it does not work. I have a error with the range description:

```
rngDoc = .Range(Start:=.Bookmarks("Start").Range.Start, End:=.Bookmarks("End").Range.End))
```

and it tells me that it cannot find the following element in the collection (translated from German "Das aufgeforderte Element ist nicht in der Sammlung vorhanden"). Has anybody an idea how else to describe the range?

```
Sub ImportPartAHoftorbilanz()

Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim rngStart As Range
Dim rngEnd As Range


'Get Wordfile and Open It
wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.docx", , _
"Browse for file containing table to be imported")
If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)
Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

With wdDoc
    Dim rngDoc As Object
    rngDoc = .Range(Start:=.Bookmarks("Start").Range.Start, End:=.Bookmarks("End").Range.End)
    rngDoc.Copy SaveChanges:=False
End With

'Paste Selection
Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Set wdDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. *"it does not work."* is not a useful error description. Instead describe what your code does vs. what you expect it to do, or where you get errors and which. Also  [“Can someone help me?” is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) because we cannot answer that. Instead ask a question related to your code.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thanks tried to change it for the better. I am new here and also new to VBA

Comment: DId you insert two bookmarks in the document with the names "Start" and "End"?

Comment: @CindyMeister yes I did Insert the two bookmarks in the document (Word-Document)

Comment: The basic problem with your code is that you've defined 'rngStart As Range' and 'rngEnd As Range'; you need to use 'rngStart As Word.Range' and 'rngEnd As Word.Range'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with the "With wdDoc" statement change the remaining code to the following:

```
With wdDoc
    Dim rngDoc As word.Range
    Set rngDoc = .Range(Start:=.Bookmarks("Start").Range.Start, End:=.Bookmarks("End").Range.End)
    rngDoc.Copy
End With

'Paste Selection
Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

wdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
Set wdDoc = Nothing
```